# Code appears to work to produce Filtered Dataframes from a nested loop, but can't save Each one to it's own variable in Pandas. Need a Pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, save

Code appears to work to produce Filtered Dataframes from a nested loop, but can't save Each one to it's own variable in Pandas.  Need a Pythonic way.

```
import pandas as pd

filelist =r'C:/Users/Owner/_APP_Local/data'

path = filelist

data = pd.read_csv(path+'/Data=X_yes.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

"""Splitting a Dataset into Multiple Datasets Dynamically"""    """This Works"""

```
i=0
data_prep=[]

for data, new_df in df.groupby('Name'):
data_prep.append(new_df)

    Time_prep = []

    for new_df, Tnew_df in new_df.groupby('Time_Frame'):
        i=0
        Time_prep.append(Tnew_df)
        data= Tnew_df

        print(data[['Date',"Name","Time_Frame"]])    # """This Works with Filtered Columns properly"""
```

Output:

```
Date            Name            Time
632 2021-07-26  FilteredName1   FilteredTime1
633 2021-07-27  FilteredName1   FilteredTime1
634 2021-07-28  FilteredName1   FilteredTime1  Would like to save as df1 in below format
635 2021-07-3 ‘ FilteredName1   FilteredTime1
636 2021-07-30  FilteredName1   FilteredTime1

Date            Name            Time
632 2021-07-26  FilteredName2   FilteredTime2
633 2021-07-27  FilteredName2   FilteredTime2
634 2021-07-28  FilteredName2   FilteredTime2  Would like to save as df2 in below format
635 2021-07-3 ‘ FilteredName2   FilteredTime2
636 2021-07-30  FilteredName2   FilteredTime2




        TFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
        globals()['dataframe' + str(new_df)]= TFrame
        d = dict(tuple(TFrame.groupby('Name')))


        file_dict = {}
        for df1 in d:
            key = df1
        file_dict[key] = df1

        for i, x in TFrame.groupby('Name'):
            globals()['dataframe' + str(i)] = x
        ('dataframe'+(i) +'_'+ Tnew_df[['Time_Frame']])=x
     print('dataframe'+(i) +'_'+ Tnew_df[['Time_Frame']])

     
     output:  
     dataframe\Name_Time1
     dataframe\Name_Time1
     dataframe\Name_Time1    Format to save in is printing out properly, but not for
     dataframe\Name_Time1    each df.
     dataframe\Name_Time1
```

"""A nested loop that works, but difficulty in saving each DataFrame result into its own variable."""

Comment: Don't store the dataframes in `globals`. Create another dictionary to hold them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what would that look like?  I can't seem to do anything with variables....Maybe a Tuple  .-   d = dict(tuple(TFrame.groupby('Market_Name'))) .  And if I go down this path, how would this work within a loop?   d [ i ] = dict(tuple(TFrame.groupby('Market_Name')))?

Comment: Why do you need to store them separately ?

Comment: I will then take a list of dataframes and send them to numerous functions that have already been built to handle dataframes.  "DRY"

Comment: You don't need  that. You  can just invoke the function in `groupby.apply` `df.groupby(['name', 'time_frame']).apply(your function goes here)`.

Comment: OK,  I will dive into the groupby.apply   I have seen it and realize it does offer quite a bit for this type of challenge.  Thanks

Comment: YES YES,  I have results coming in.  Thanks for Help.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237269/discussion-between-davis-rogers-and-psidom).

Comment: don't waste time for separated variables - keep result in new list, dictionary or dataframe. It will be more useful.

Comment: I think the following solution is Pythonically appropriate.